# HTML Form Directing to URL with a Question Mark (?)

Tags: html, forms, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect users to a URL that includes a question mark. The issue is on click users are directed to the URL leading up to the '?'. So if my designated URL is [www.abc.com/help?blahblah](http://www.abc.com/help?blahblah) users will be directed to [www.abc.com/help](http://www.abc.com/help).

The problem is I don't know whether or not there will be a '?' in the URL, so I cannot have a blanket case..

My form is as follows

```
<form action="<%=reviewLink%>">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success small-button">
            <i class="fab fa-review"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success large-button"> Review
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it on my own. I went ahead and added the following to the button elements.

```
<a href="<%=reviewLink%>" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
```